# Can not split the arrays loaded from csv file

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, csv, numpy

I use python 3.6 want to split the array but I find what I load [array](https://github.com/thinksource/randomforest/blob/master/table1.csv) it does not have the second dimension.

I use:

```
path1 = 'table1.csv'
data1 = np.loadtxt(path1, dtype=[('id', int),('VAR1', int),('VAR2', int),('VAR3', float),('OUTCOME', int)], delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
```

when I try to split it, or I want to get the shape of I loaded, I get wrong:

```
>>> data1.shape
(24999,)
```

since it do not have second dimension, I can not use

```
>>>numpy.split(data1, (4,), axis=1)
```

I just want to split the vector by 4th column, but sicne the x-dimension is empty, I can not do it. how to make the shape of array like：

```
 (24999, 5)
```

How to get the second dimension and split the array?
I expect to get split the data and return the

```
x,y=np.split(data, (4,), axis=1)
```

x is the x1,x2 x3 ... with parameters and y is the outcome and then I can learn the model from x.

Comment: Your reading the data as a structured array type, so it will be one dimensional. Why not just split without `axis=1`?

Comment: Since, I want split by column not row. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: But you've used a structred data type, it will be one-dimensional.

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish, btw?

Comment: I just want to join 2 tables, and then split it. if I do not use structed data, the table can not know join by which column.

Comment: How do you want to split it? What is the final output you expect?

Comment: @Kanak Yes, I set correct delimiter, you can get the original csv file but the link https://github.com/thinksource/randomforest/blob/master/table1.csv dtype should be int. or it can be float, but the 'id' coumn should be int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, with that `dtype` you have 'rows' and 'fields', but not columns.  Fields are accessed by name, not number.  And `split` does not work across fields.

You could access the 5th field with `data1['OUTCOME']`.  You could access a set of columns with a list of names, eg.  `data1[['VAR1','VAR2','VAR3']].copy()`.  The `copy` isn't always needed but be prepared to use it.

Alternatively load the file in 2 steps, with `usecols` to select different columns.  Adjust the `dtype` accordingly.

Or load with `dtype=float`, and get a `(n,5)` float array.  Then you can do a column split.

Answer (score 0):

It actually seems that you want your vector as a row-vector since you set `axis=1` (which means that you want to split it at the 4th column). Why not add the second dimension ? You may thus want to do

```
>>> data1 = data1.reshape((1,data1.shape[0]))
>>> numpy.split(data1, (4,), axis=1)
```

Or, another solution, is not setting `axis` parameter

```
>>> data1 = np.loadtxt(path1, dtype=[('id', int),('VAR1', int),('VAR2', int),('VAR3', float),('OUTCOME', int)], delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
>>> numpy.split(data1, (4,))
```

Or Try not specifying dtype. You will stil bel able to turn your ids into integers in a second processing stage.

```
>>> data1 = np.loadtxt(path1, delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
```

Comment: Yes, I just want to split the vector by 4th column, but sicne the x-dimension is empty, I can not do it.

Comment: I edit question, pls refresh. I want split by column not raws.

Comment: I can not do your way, That is because actually my data from two tables instead of one table, I need to join the two table and get full parameters and then I split to array as input and output.

Comment: I need data =numpy.lib.recfunctions.join_by('id', data1,data2, jointype='inner' usemask=False), if the 'id' column not named and not int how the computer know the way to join together?

Comment: @user504909. Column names have no importance since you skip the first row, and You will still be able to turn your ids into integers in a second processing stage.

Comment: @user504909 Actually, take time to read the other answer, better than mine. Everything is explained. ***You will see***, hpaulj's solution works.